# SSRS The request failed with HTTP status 502: notresolvable

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I use Visual Studio 2015 for editing reports on Report Server 2014. All of a sudden I could not publish my editions anymore. I got the error:

> The request failed with HTTP status 502: notresolvable. (Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsClient).

Every configuration remains the same, I mean, my account on AD and the report server is online and the reports are working. I can do maintenances using Report Builder, which is saving me until now. I have my reports in version control on VSTS, just in case. The SSRS was updated from 2008R2 to 2014 recently (a couple months ago), but only very recently I coud not deploy from inside VS.
What more information is relevant to put here so I can get help from community? I have already searched for solutions but nothing found here or at Microsoft KB.

Comment: Have you tested the connection in the data source?

Comment: All connections for database are working. Where can I test further connections I can't remember. Some tip? My problem still persists, thanks.